# Angular material: matInput don`t float mat-label

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular12, angular16

I just updated angular application from Angular version 11 to Angular 16 also with angular material. After update matInput don`t float mat-label. Text is overlapping with mat label.

Can someone suggest me what could be the reason?

[image]

This is my project's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "browser": {
    "os": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "ng test --no-watch --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 150,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "arrowParens": "always"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.20",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-fonts": "^4.0.1",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata": "^4.1.21",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.4",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^16.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^16.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^16.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "keycloak-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^21.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "7.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "tls": "^0.0.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
}
```

Followed below link but issue still persist:
[https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7661](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: have you updated styles.css file according to migration guide from docuemntation? In material 13 there were changes in styling

Comment: No Adrian, can you please share that migration link. I am using styles.scss. I did not find anything related this on https://update.angular.io/?v=11.0-16.0

Comment: Check out [theming guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) and match your code with the tutorial. Some functions have been renamed but I don't remember where was the migration guide and the specific version